# Problem Reading Excel File Having Single Quote in Sheet Name using OLEDB c#

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

Giving Error 
Invalid Character

```
string sSheetName="Nov'16";
dt = new DataTable();
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [" + sSheetName+ "]", conn);
da.Fill(dt);
ds.Tables.Add(dt);
```

Comment: Try putting a $ in front of sheet name.  The dollar sign indicates a System name.  The excel workbook has a hidden list of system object and the worksheet names are in the list of system objects.  The dollar sign is needed to indicate to look in the system object for the name.

Comment: Thank you, i tried Nov'16$ also but still same error.

Comment: You need the dollar sign.  Open the excel workbook and copy the sheet name and paste into the c# code.  Then add the dollar sign at the end.  It should work.  It is possible the single quote is not really a single quote.

Comment: Thank you @jdweng. I followed the step that you mentioned, still facing the same issue. Please help

Comment: The command has three types 1) Text 2) Table 3) Stored Procedure. 
 It is possible the wrong type is being used.  So add : da.SelectCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

Comment: What is your connection string?  Does it include header row?  Excel drivers (ACE or Jet) does some real funny things.  It tries to guess types.  It has been a long time but I occasionally have issues with first column of data.  The drivers under some conditions expect the first column to be row number and if finds strings than will get a invalid character.  Do not remember all the conditions this happens.  But when there is a combination of numbers and strings in first column this can happen.

Answer (score 1):

This may be of help to someone. For some reason, mine was substituting the single quote with two single quotes when I was reading in the sheet names. I ran the following and it was fixed:

```
                                            comm.CommandText = "Select * from [" + sheetName.Replace("''","'") + "]";
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of old interop you can try to use one of the modern libraries, for example [ExcelDataReader](https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader)

```
using (var stream = File.Open("C:\\Temp\\test.xlsx", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    using (var reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(stream))
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
            {
                var value = reader.GetValue(i)?.ToString() ?? string.Empty;
            }
        }
    }
}
```